# Is there a substance that gets stronger when damaged?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, materials

I have "ossification" stat in my game but i don't think the name doesn't fit the context. Armors can have this stat; basically the armor becomes stronger when damaged, the effect works 5 second then resets back original armor stat (I mean "stronger" with: defense stat increase and player gets less damage)

I want rename this stat, and I'd like science based term, is there any substance do you know?

Comment: Please read the tag description: Do not use this tag as the only tag on a question because it describes how the question should be answered, not the topic.

Comment: Obligatory ["nanomachines son"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhMsboqMMzs) comment.

Comment: Thanks i understand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a metal crystal bends, it does so by way of "dislocations" -- imperfections in the crystal lattice of atoms -- moving through the crystal grains of the metal.  In some cases, you can hear this; a block of tin will "cry" when bent, as the dislocations move faster than the local speed of sound.

Most metals, however, are subject to "work hardening" -- as the material is deformed dislocations multiply, pin against one another, and increase the resistance to further deformation.  This makes the material harder, and up to a point, stronger (go too far, and it can become brittle, of course).

The problem with this is that it's a permanent change, absent some intervention (annealing is the usual treatment -- heating above a temperature specific to the material, then cooling slowly enough to allow "recrystallization" to reset the count of crystal dislocations).

What you want, then, is a material (let's call it "handwavium" because as far as I know this can't actually exist) that self-anneals at common ambient temperatures, over your "cool down" period.  Bash it hard enough to cause permanent deformation, work hardening sets in and the material gets stronger -- but then as it anneals itself, it reverts back to its original condition.  You could even handwave further, and postulate that your material not only reverts to its original hardness condition, but to the shape it was last forged into (at much higher temperature, so the change can be permanent -- this is similar to the commercial "memory metal" Nitinol, though that require application of mild heat to activate the memory effect).

Answer (score 5):

Much armour is made of overlapping plates or leaves of metal.

What if instead, the armour were made of overlapping pouches of something special.

[Oobleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid#Oobleck) (AKA corn-starch and water) behaves in a remarkable way, it's like a thick runny liquid but when you apply sudden force, it goes rock-hard for a couple of seconds. Sometimes referred to as a non-Newtonian fluid, and made famous in various YouTube demonstrations of people running across paddling-pools full of it, then sinking when they stand still.

A failure-mode for this might be when the pouches get little nicks and cuts or around the seams as the threads give-out, eventually the oobleck will run-out and be gone - the armour becomes as protective as a tatty leather suite.

So there's your Oobleck armour.

**Caveat:**

The armour will leak after being damaged, leaving a trail that may be followed by friend or foe.

Comment: Non-Newtonian solid

Comment: [Liquid Armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_Armor)

Comment: Hi @gre_gor, why not write an answer using that (I'm kicking myself that I'd missed it).

Comment: Because I don't know how to write a good enough answer about it. And mine answer would be too similar to yours. You can add it to yours, about real attempts at that kind of armor.